# How to underline Text in react native android

Tags: react-native

There is a property textDecorationLine to underline text but that works oly on iOS. how to do that in android? Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Comment: Currently there is no way to do that properly on Android. However it should come in the near future. See [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/3819) for reference.

Comment: Okay, Looks like I have to handle it differently for android. Thanks for reply @mbernardeau

Comment: It's coming in the [0.25 release](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.25.0-rc), in two weeks

Comment: @mbernardeau oh, thats awesome news. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up making two component

> text.android.js

and

> text.ios.js

. 
And in android one I just draw a view with very thick height(1px) below the text which looks like underline.

Answer (score 1):

In Android use this Property: Remove the Underline

```
<TextInput underlineColorAndroid="transparent" />
```